# how to read #3 in eagi, i tried with dd but not get success

Tags: speech-recognition, asterisk, gcloud

I want to voice streaming between asterisk and google ASR by using eagi, but when i used eagi, not able to read sound file on fd 3, how I read it?

I already tried with dd command, but it is showing me 
    "dd: failed to open ‘/dev/fd/3’: No such file or directory"

transcribe.eagi code

```
 `$BLOCKS = 312;
$AUDIO_FILE = '/tmp/ddff.raw';
shell_exec("dd if=/dev/fd/3 count=$BLOCKS of=$AUDIO_FILE");`
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use some high-level interface like https://github.com/sangoma/phpagi. They expose audio stream as $audio. They use the following logic to open audio stream:

```
    if(file_exists('/proc/' . getmypid() . '/fd/3')) {
        // this should work on linux
        $this->audio = fopen('/proc/' . getmypid() . '/fd/3', 'r');
    } elseif(file_exists('/dev/fd/3')) {
        // this should work on BSD. may need to mount fdescfs if this fails
        $this->audio = fopen('/dev/fd/3', 'r');
    } else {
        $this->conlog('Unable to open audio stream');
    }
```